# How to make transparent text appear in SVG

Tags: html, svg

```
<svg>
        <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" opacity="0">Hello</text>
        <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="click" dur="0.3s" from="0" to="1" restart="never" fill="freeze"></animate>
</svg>
```

Above is the code, I want to use SVG to make a transparent text appear. I am new to coding especially SVG, thanks for any help and creative thoughts.

Comment: Hello! looks like you forgot to add your code, could you add it?

Comment: You need to close the text tag after the animate element. However this means that you need to know where the text is so that you can click on it. Alternatively you can give the svg an id and use this id to begin the animation: `begin="svgId.click"`

Comment: Sorry, can't you see the code above? I am new here and I thought I have upload the code, here is the code for your reference<svg>
        <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" opacity="0">Hello</text>
        <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="click" dur="0.3s" from="0" to="1" restart="never" fill="freeze"></animate>
</svg>

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is to make the animate element a child of the text element.

```html
<svg>
        <text x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" opacity="0">Hello
        <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="click" dur="0.3s" from="0" to="1" restart="never" fill="freeze"></animate>
        </text>
</svg>
```

Otherwise you could add a href or xlink:href attribute to the animate tag to tell it that it's the text element you want to affect

```html
<svg>
        <text id="t" x="0" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" opacity="0">Hello
        </text>
        <animate attributeName="opacity" href="#t" begin="click" dur="0.3s" from="0" to="1" restart="never" fill="freeze"></animate>
</svg>
```